# Creación de excepciones en java. Ingreso de datos numéricos

Tags: java, poo

```
public class Operaciones {

    private static Cliente listaCliente[] = new Cliente[5];
    private static BufferedReader entrada = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    private static Scanner entrada1 = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void cargarDatosClientes() throws IOException {
        System.out.println("**INGRESE DATOS DEL CLIENTE**");
        for (int i = 0; i < listaCliente.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
            Cliente cliente = new Cliente();

            System.out.println("Nombre Completo");
            cliente.setNombreCompleto(entrada.readLine());

            System.out.println("Nro Cuenta");
            cliente.setNumeroCuenta(entrada.readLine());

            try {
                System.out.println("Saldo inicial");
                cliente.setSaldoInicial(entrada1.nextInt());
                System.out.println("Total articulo");
                cliente.setTotalArticulos(entrada1.nextInt());
                System.out.println("Total creditos");
                cliente.setTotalCreditos(entrada1.nextInt());
                System.out.println("Limite credito");
                cliente.setLimiteCredito(entrada1.nextInt());

            } catch (Excepcion e) {
                e.mensajePersonalizado();

            }

            listaCliente[i] = cliente;
        }

    }

    public static void imprimirDatos() {
        for (int i = 0; i < listaCliente.length; i++) {
            long nroSaldo = (listaCliente[i].getSaldoInicial() + listaCliente[i].getTotalArticulos()) - listaCliente[i].getTotalCreditos();
            System.out.println("---------------------------------------------");
            if (nroSaldo > listaCliente[i].getLimiteCredito()) {
                System.err.println("El cliente " + listaCliente[i].getNombreCompleto() + " se excedio el límite de credito ");
                System.out.println("");
            } else {
                System.out.printf("El cliente " + listaCliente[i].getNombreCompleto() + " no se excedio al límite de credito");
                System.out.println("");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Excepcion extends InputMismatchException {

    public Excepcion() {
        super();
    }

    public Excepcion(String string) {
        super(string);
    }

    public void mensajePersonalizado() {
        System.err.println("Error: Dato ingresado incorrecto, ingrese solo numeros.");
    }

}
```

---

No entiendo porque no funciona mi excepción creada. Debo crear una excepcion asi..
Error: Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No te funciona porque tiene un error de concepto relacionado con la herencia y el polimorfismo.

Estás creando una clase que hereda de `InputMismatchException`, o lo que es lo mismo, un nuevo tipo más específico que `InputMismatchException`. Por lo tanto, y teniendo en cuenta las siguientes instancias: :

```
InputMismatchException padre = new InputMismatchException();
Excepcion hijo = new Excepcion();
```

esta asiganción sería correcta

```
padre = hijo;
```

Lo anterior se debe a que la clase hijo, la más específica (`Excepcion`), puede comportarse como su clase padre, la más general (InputMismatchException) o cualquiera de sus ascendientes, ya que esta incluye todas sus características y comportamiento; y le agrega otros.

Por el contrario, esta otra asignación

```
hijo = padre;
```

provocaría un error de compilación, ya que como el padre es una clase más general que el hijo, no tiene sus nuevas características y comportamientos; lo que se traduce en que no puede comportarse como tal.

A modo de resumen hasta ahora: un hijo puede ser tratado como su padre, pero un padre no puede tratarse como a su hijo.

Teniendo en mente lo anterior, analicemos como funcionan los try-catch. Si en el código del `try` se lanza una excepción, se analiza si la excepción lanzada puede ser tratada como alguna de las excepciones definidas en los correspondientes `catch`(el análisis se hace en el mismo orden en que estos `catch` fueron definidos).

Supongamos este ejemplo:

```
try {
    // código que puede lanzar alguna excepción
} catch (Excepcion e) {
    // código
}
```

Si la excepción que se lanza es de tipo `Excepcion`, o algún subtipo de esta, entrará en el `catch` y se ejecutará el código dentro de su cuerpo. Porque como vimos anteriormente, cualquier hijo de `Excepcion` puede tratarse como este. Si la excepción es de tipo `InputMismatchException`, no entraría al `catch` porque al ser un padre (o supertipo) de `Excepcion`, no puede tratarse como tal. Esto provoca que la excepción lanzada no sea tratada y por ende sea "relanzada" (pro llamarle de alguna manera) por el método `cargarDatosClientes()` hacia quien lo ha ejecutado (y así sucesivamente si no se captura, hasta que llega a la máquina virtual y generalmente se detiene la ejecución del programa).

Para solucionar tu problema debes agregar un `catch` como este

```
catch (InputMismatchException e) {
    // código
}
```

y en el código de este `catch` enviar el mensaje que deseas.

Comment: Pero no hay alguna manera de crear un clase y crear la excepción ahí?.  He probado creando una con la excepción ArithmeticException y me funcionó(Me refiero a otro programa). Pero esta no le pillo aun..

Comment: No puedes crear un subtipo de una excepción X e intentar capturarla utilizando dicho subtipo en el catch. No se que será lo que probaste con ArithmeticException, pero estoy seguro que no fue lo mismo que intentas acá.

Comment: En fin, entonces digamos que no funciona por el Throwable?.Pd: Soy nuevo en la programación. Soy novato.

Comment: No se de que Throwable hablas. No funciona porque la excepción que se lanza no coincide con la del catch. Solo coincidiría si `InputMismatchException` fuera un subtipo de `Excepcion`, y es al revés.

Comment: Bueno vale, investigare más. Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Empieza por herencia y polimorfismo, para que puedas entender lo de las excepciones.

Comment: Gracias bro, lo hare. Pero asi empezamos en la universidad. Tendre que adelantarme. Gracias por la ayuda!!

Answer (score 0):

Las excepciones en java no funcionan así.

En un bloque `catch` de la siguiente forma:

```
try {
    ...
} catch (Exception e) {
    ...
}
```

Se capturará cualquier excepción que sea una subclase de `Exception`

Pero en tu caso tienes la siguiente jerarquía de excepciones:

```
java.lang.Object
  java.lang.Throwable
    java.lang.Exception
      java.lang.RuntimeException
        java.util.NoSuchElementException
          java.util.InputMismatchException
            tu.package.Excepcion
```

Al declarar un `catch(Excepcion e) {...}` solo estas capturando las *subclases* de `Excepcion` incluyéndola, pero no sus *superclases*. Vale decir, no capturará `InputMismatchException`